# Javascript: Sorting Objects Challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

I have a bit of a challenge. I am working on a physics application with javascript. The two main objects being used are

```
var force = new Object();
var torque = new Object();
with properties
force.magnitude = newArray();
force.lengthfromorigin = new Array();
force.count;
torque.lengthfromorigin= new Array();
torque.count;
```

now, I'd like to sort these two objects into an array based on their respective lengthfromorigins

Example: force.lengthfromorigin = [5,8] and torque.lengthfromorigin=[2,6]
so their order in this newArray would be [ torque[0], force[0], torque[1], force[1] ]

**My question** is it possible to have an array of different objects sorted by their respective properties, and to then use this array in a function which will make decisions based on which object is at the index. Also will I need to have an id property in each respective object to identify if the object is a torque or force.

Example:

```
if(newArray[i] == torque)
    //do stuff
else
    //do other stuff.
```

Comment: 1) likely, 2) please use your first  example in the next example

Comment: I think you're trying to solve too much at once. I'd start by coding a sorting method for an array of integers, then work your way up from there.

Comment: its pseudo code @PsychHalf ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

Let me explain the algorithm:

1. Create a new array let it be called ***A***.
2. For each objects in `objects`:

   2.1 Let the current object be called ***obj***.

   2.2 Use `map` to generate a new array called ***tuples*** of *[obj, num]* tuples 
       for each `lengthFromOrigin` numbers of ***obj***.

   3.3 Push all items of ***tuples*** into ***A***.
3. Sort ***A*** on ***tuple[1]*** (which is the number) ascending.

```
var objects = [
        { type: 'force', lengthFromOrigin: [5, 8] },
        { type: 'torque', lengthFromOrigin: [2, 6] }
    ],
    sorted = objects.reduce(function (arr, obj) {
        arr.push.apply(arr, obj.lengthFromOrigin.map(function (num) {
            return [obj, num];
        }));

        return arr;           
    }, []).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a[1] - b[1];    
    });

console.log(sorted);
```

Then you can loop over `sorted` and easily identify if it's a *torque* or *force* by looking at the first element in the tuple.

```
sorted.forEach(function (tuple) {
    console.log(tuple[0].type, tuple[1]);
});

//torque 2
//force 5
//torque 6
//force 8
```

Comment: @bala, You can obviously encapsulate the algorithm in a function if you plan to do this often ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **Yes**,

But you have to identify each object before you access their properties. In your case Both of the objects have a common property called **lengthfromorigin** which can be used to sort them properly.

To identify each object you can use a property like **ID** or **Name**.

```
if(Mydata[i].Name = 'torque'){
  //your code goes here
}
else if(Mydata[i].Name = 'force'){
  //your code goes here
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Why not just use object oriented principles and put a commonly named method on each object type that can execute the desired code for that type of object so you don't have to look at what type it is?